# form select is not remembering value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Select helper is not remembering its database value. But Text field is remembering. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @product], :remote => true ) do |f| %>      
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.select(:search_status, ["0","1","2"]) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your form setup implies that :search_status is an attribute of @product, but it sounds more like a standalone variable, in which case you would need some handling specific to the variable in your controller.  It would be helpful if you could post your controller (and possibly model) code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that search_status is an integer and not matching the strings in your array. Does it work if you use `[0,1,2]` instead?

Comment: Thank you sir. Yes it was about type of column.